# EntityFramework Generic Repository Pattern, OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, out-of-memory, repository-pattern

I am seeing a very weird behavior and I have spent 2 days trying to figure out what is going on. Any help is appreciated.

Over all Problem. I am using the Entity Framework injunction with the Repository Pattern. I am getting an OutOfMemoryExpecption if I don't specify the concrete type of the DbContext. However, specifying the concrete type really ruins the Generic Pattern I am trying to acheive. Does anyone know why this is happening and what is the difference is between ConcreteDbContext.Models and DbContext.Set?

Note: I am dealing with a dataset that is about 2 million recrods.

***OutOfMemoryException Scenario***

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Add(T entity);
    T Update(T entity);
    T Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    ...
}

  public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
          //Intentionally Left Blank
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<MyModel> Models{ get; set; }
}



 public abstract class EfRepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class

{
     private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

     protected EfRepositoryBase(DbContext context)
    {
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

     protected IDbSet<T> Table
    {
        get { return _dbSet; }
    }
  ...
 }


public class MyRepository : EfRepositoryBase<MyModel>, IMyRepository
{

    public MyRepository (DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    //Example Method
    public IList<DateTime> DoStuff(DateTime start, int lookforward)
    {
        var startRangeEnd = start.AddDays(lookforward);
        var startRange =
            Table.AsNoTracking()
                   .Where(s => s.eventDate >= start && s.eventDate <= startRangeEnd)
                   .OrderBy(o => o.eventDate)
                   .Select(s => s.eventDate).Distinct();
        return startRange.ToList();
    }

   .... //More methods that do Linq Queries
 }
```

***Working Scenario*** Notice in the working scenario I need to return the Context in my EfBaseRepository then in my Implementation cast it as the concrete type to get access to the Models Dbset. (I could of also returned MyDbContext in the EFBaseRepository, but I am trying to avoid having the concrete type MyDbContext).

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Add(T entity);
    T Update(T entity);
    T Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    ...
}

  public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext (string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
          //Intentionally Left Blank
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual IDbSet<MyModel> Models{ get; set; }
}



 public abstract class EfRepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class

{
     private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;
     private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

     protected EfRepositoryBase(DbContext context)
    {
        _dbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }

     protected DbContext Table
    {
        get { return _dbContext; }
    }
  ...
 }


public class MyRepository : EfRepositoryBase<MyModel>, IMyRepository
{

    public MyRepository (DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected MyDbContext Ctx
     { get { return Table as MyDbContext; } }

    //Example Method
    public IList<DateTime> DoStuff(DateTime start, int lookforward)
    {
        var startRangeEnd = start.AddDays(lookforward);
        var startRange =
            Ctx.Models.AsNoTracking()
                   .Where(s => s.eventDate >= start && s.eventDate <= startRangeEnd)
                   .OrderBy(o => o.eventDate)
                   .Select(s => s.eventDate).Distinct();
        return startRange.ToList();
    }

   .... //More methods that do Linq Queries
 }
```

Comment: Is `protected IDbSet Table` a typo (`IDbSet<T>`)?

Comment: Yes that was a typo, it is IDbSet<T>

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behavior of `Unbounded result set`. An unbounded result set is where a query does not explicitly limit the number of returned results from a query. [more info here](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof/learn/alert/unboundedresultset)

To fix it you need to start paging the results using `Take` and `Skip` methods:

```
const int pageSize = 25;
var list = ctx.Table1.OrderBy(g => g.Id)
        .Select(g => ....)
    .Skip(pageSize * pageNumber)
        .Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but that doesn't really answer my question. I want to know why DbContext will return fine but DbSet goes out of memory. I've noticed DbContext implements IDisposable and DbSet doesn't. But Like I mentioned in my question I very unfamiliar with how this works.

Comment: add `2 million records` to a list (more or less, as you mentioned) and then observe its memory usage footprint + memory usage of the database server.